# is there a way to suppress generation of overview-tree.html in javadoc?

Tags: javadoc

When javadoc generates the overview-tree.html file for a library I'm working with, it produces a 372M monstrosity. This is the tree view file for the whole library.

I would like to dispense with this file, while still getting the tree files for individual classes. The -notree javadoc option is not the answer as I still want the tree files for individual classes.

I can think of various hacks to get around this problem, but I'd rather have a clean solution out of the box. Is there one?

Answer (score 0):

If you work with such a large Java projects, it is not too wise to create huge number of html files using javadoc and and have a large navigation tree. You will slow down the web server with many small html javadoc files that need to be served by apache.

There are projects that create a sqlite database from Java javadoc and skip " -notree -noindex" options all together (since they do not need to be created). You do not need even trees for each separate project. One possible option is to use Doc2SQL http://jwork.org/doc2sql/ project that claims to handle GBs of data with Javadoc files without creating large navigation trees.